# How to discover SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) on network without connecting to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, service-discovery

I was able to discover SSIS on local computer, but the problem appears when I try to discover SSIS instances on the network without connecting to a SQL Server first.

Is there any method, or library which would allow me to just check if SSIS is installed on network. 
I don't need any additional data, I just want to detect whether is SSIS installed.

I was able to discover SSIS after I connect to SQL Server instance on that network server, but I need a way to discover without connecting to SQL Server instance

I expect to get information that SSIS is installed or not on the network computers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSIS services are named `MsDtsServer##0` starting with `MsDtsServer100` for SQL Server 2008.

```
SQL Server        Service Name
SQL 2008          MsDtsServer100
SQL 2012          MsDtsServer110
SQL 2014          MsDtsServer120
SQL 2016          MsDtsServer130
SQL 2017          MsDtsServer140
SQL 2019          MsDtsServer150
```

You can use WMI or the Windows Services API to look for these named services on your SQL servers.